# Ionic list is cut off at the bottom

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am displaying a normal list view getting data but the bottom is cut off.

In my css, I have:  ]

```
.scroll { 
    height: 100% 
}
```

My HTML is:

```
 <ion-content scroll="true" ng-controller="CategoriesCtrl" overflow-scroll="true">
<ion-list>
 <ion-item ng-repeat="category in categories | orderBy: 'id':true"
       href="#/category/{{category.id}}"
       class="item item-thumbnail-left catthumb list cat">
        <img ng-src="{{category.acf.thumbnail.url}}" class="catthumb">
        <span style="font-size: 21px; font-weight: 400;">{{category.name}}</span>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that those BR tags were out of desperation. They shouldn't be used for layout. Why are you not using standard list markup? http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/

Comment: I switched to the standard list, but the bottom is stil cut off unless I use BR tags.  Without those tags, it's cut off.

Comment: Could you modify this fiddle and fork it to demonstrate? http://jsfiddle.net/556GL/23/

Comment: I changed the original post to what I changed the HTML to so it's the standard list if that helps

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the closing ion-item tag.  It should be:

```
<ion-content scroll="true" ng-controller="CategoriesCtrl" overflow-scroll="true">
<ion-list>
 <ion-item ng-repeat="category in categories | orderBy: 'id':true"
   href="#/category/{{category.id}}"
   class="item item-thumbnail-left catthumb list cat">
    <img ng-src="{{category.acf.thumbnail.url}}" class="catthumb">
        <span style="font-size: 21px; font-weight: 400;">{{category.name}}</span>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happen when we added another view level header or footer.

Simple solution is to add spacer div in the end of ur page with the height of ur page level header.
[For more info](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ioncontent-spacer-css-issue-with-beta-14/14356)